# Reload all sections except first and second

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I have Tablview which contains number of sections.

**First Section -** it's contain search textbox
**second section -** its's contain UIView
**other sections -**  this section which i want to reload at the time of searching.
**UPDATE**
  I am set countdic and tableview like below :-
**1. set countdic**

```
self.countDic.updateValue(1, forKey: "0")// this is for First section
self.countDic.updateValue(0, forKey: "1")//this is for second section
for i in 0..<arra1.count {
    self.countDic.updateValue(array.count, forKey: "\(i + 2)")//[index : arraylist.count]
}
```

**2. Here is my tableview setup**

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return countDic["\(section)"]!
 }

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return countDic.count
}
```

**3. Here i am reload tableview** 
This is from **shouldChangeCharactersIn** of UITextfield

```
 let indexSet = IndexSet(integersIn: 2..<self.TblView.numberOfSections)
 self.TblView.reloadSections(indexSet, with: .bottom)
```

but it's crash the app with Error :

> ** reason: 'attempt to insert section 3 but there are only 3 sections after the update'
>   **

Can anyone suggest how to done ?

Answer (score 5):

This is Swift.

- `NS(Make)Range` is inappropriate
  (The second parameter of `NSMakeRange` is the **length** not the *end index* by the way)
- `NSMutableIndexSet` is inappropriate

Use the Swift capabilities:

```
let indexSet = IndexSet(integersIn: 2..<self.countDic.count)
self.TblView.reloadSections(indexSet, with: .bottom)
```

Comment: I have face another error : attempt to insert section 3 but there are only 3 sections after the update'

Comment: Please ask a new question and provide more information

Answer (score 1):

Use this function to reloads the specified sections

```
func reloadSections(_ sections: IndexSet, 
               with animation: UITableViewRowAnimation)
```

If you don't want reload first 2 sections of tableview then

```
tableView.reloadSections(IndexSet(2..<tableView.numberOfSection), with: .none)
```

Cheers!!!

Comment: Its gives me fatal error when i have only one record in updated array after search 

fatal error: Can't form Range with upperBound < lowerBound

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**In Obj-c**

```
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(2, totalsection - 2);
NSIndexSet *section = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:range];                                     
[self.tableView reloadSections:section withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone]
```

**In Swift**

```
var range = NSRange(location: 2, length: totalsection - 2)
var section = IndexSet(indexesIn: range)
tableView.reloadSections(section, with: .none)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
let indexSet = IndexSet(integersIn: 1..<self.TblView.numberOfSections-1)

self.TblView.reloadSections(indexSet, with: .bottom)
```